# How do you print View fields on Twig?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have a view and added the title as a field.

For example: How do I print the title?

> In Drupal 7 it was as simple as
>
> **views-view-fields--[viewname].tpl.php**
>
> ```
> <?php print $fields["title"]->content; ?>
> ```

#### How do we do this in Drupal 8?

I have created **views-view-fields--[viewname].html.twig**

I thought it might be `{{ fields.title }}` but I get the classic error message like so:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

I then tried `{{ field.title }}`, `{{ title }}` and `{{ content.title }}` but nothing prints.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After eating dinner, washing the dishes, playing around with it and reading the comments in **views-view-fields.html.twig** located in `core\modules\views\templates`

```
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display all the fields in a row.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - view: The view in use.
 * - fields: A list of fields, each one contains:
 *   - content: The output of the field.
 *   - raw: The raw data for the field, if it exists. This is NOT output safe.
 *   - class: The safe class ID to use.
 *   - handler: The Views field handler controlling this field.
 *   - inline: Whether or not the field should be inline.
 *   - wrapper_element: An HTML element for a wrapper.
 *   - wrapper_attributes: List of attributes for wrapper element.
 *   - separator: An optional separator that may appear before a field.
 *   - label: The field's label text.
 *   - label_element: An HTML element for a label wrapper.
 *   - label_attributes: List of attributes for label wrapper.
 *   - label_suffix: Colon after the label.
 *   - element_type: An HTML element for the field content.
 *   - element_attributes: List of attributes for HTML element for field content.
 *   - has_label_colon: A boolean indicating whether to display a colon after
 *     the label.
 *   - element_type: An HTML element for the field content.
 *   - element_attributes: List of attributes for HTML element for field content.
 * - row: The raw result from the query, with all data it fetched.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_fields()
 */
```

`{{ fields.title.content }}` worked for me. In hindsight it's very similar to the [D7 code](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199325/how-do-you-print-view-fields-on-twig/199329), duh, lol.

For other fields:

`{{ fields.machine_name.content }}` What's the machine name? You can find them under the [Machine Name column](https://www.drupal.org/files/field-ui-machine-name.png) in the Manage Fields of your content type or block.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above in views-view-fields.html.twig but not able to print any single field according to the above-mentioned method. I debug **fields** using kint() it shows 'nothing' array on the top not showing all fields. only field.content is rendering all fields.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured a way using kint.

Inside your views-view-unformatted.html.twig use the following code to display your individual fields:

```
{% for row in rows %}

{{ row.content['#view'].style_plugin.render_tokens[ loop.index0 ]['{{ YOUR_FIELD_NAME }}'] }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Nice, thx for sharing :-)

Answer (score -1):

An easier way to do this is to install [HTML Field Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/html_field_formatter)

Then, go to your field display settings and pick the new HTML formatter. It works with Views in D8, too

Comment: Sorry but your answer has nothing to do with the question. The question asks how to print a field in **twig** (template file). Why would anyone install an HTML field formatter when you can already use HTML on Twig (template file).