# How to theme views fields seperately

Tags: views, theming, 8

I'm theming a view which name is testimonials, I would like to make the view block a slider, so I'm creating the twig file as views-view-unformatted--testimonials.html.twig.

When I inspect I'm getting {{ row.content }} from the default template. I would like to give div to each and every field I'm getting inside the twig.

How do I access the field contents in the twig.

I've a number of views for each view, I would like to theme it different ways, so can I created views-view-fields for each view?

Comment: @Smalution I've edited my question, please check it.

Comment: Yes, use views-view-fields for the row or views-view-field for single fields. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x

Comment: yes, just create `views-view-fields--[view-name].html.twig` so in your case `views-view-fields--testimonials.html.twig`

Comment: @NoSssweat  How do I access my fields in it ?

Comment: `How do I access my fields in it ?` see [How do you print View fields on Twig?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199325/how-do-you-print-view-fields-on-twig)